# When it's called actionPerformed?

Tags: java, event-handling, awt, actionlistener, actionevent

When I add a object `o1` to a button with `addActionListener()`, for what actions is the `actionPerformed()` of `o1` called? This is available for `JTextField`?

Answer (score 2):

actionPerformed is called when user performs any operation on that swing component. ActionListner can be added every Swing component. So yes you can add it on the JTextField. But it gets called only in case if somebody press enter key on JTextField. For other actions you need to add other listners such as DocumentListner.

Answer (score 1):

`actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` is a abstract method of ActionListener interface. You should add it following  way.

```
 button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
       //............
     }
  });
```

> Is this available for JtextField?

**Yes**, this is available for JTextField.

Answer (score 1):

For a `JButton` the `ActionListener` is called when the button is clicked.

The `ActionListener` of a `JTextField` is fired when Enter is pressed.

This is explained in the documentation.

Comment: On this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html#addActionListener%28java.awt.event.ActionListener%29) doesn't say anything about that the jTextField call actionPerformed only when the user press ENTER.Where i find a explanation for all Swing Component(JTextField,JButton,...) ?

Comment: @Blocked In the introduction in the 7th paragraph which starts with *How the text field consumes VK_ENTER events depends on whether the text field has any action listeners.*